# WhatsApp icon randomly changes its association and starts the camera

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

The phone is Google Pixel 4a. I created the shortcut for WhatsApp by dragging the application icon to the home screen in the normal way, but the icon randomly changes its association and it starts the camera instead.

The correct association is restored by shutting down the phone and rebooting. But this has happened 3 times in as many days. Never did it until this last week. No new apps installed or setting changed.

Why and how to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: I have the same device and it only happened once with me. I went to Whatsapp posted an image using camera from Whatsapp to a contact. Exited Whatsapp.. After that no issues